# Implementing pagination in Angular Material with Django rest frameork

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, angular-material, angular-pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in my Angular Material that will work with the data coming from my Django server but I haven't gotten it right.

Here is my customer.component.ts

```
export class CustomerComponent {

  customers: Customer[] = []
  dataSource: any;
  displayedcolumns: string[] = ['name', 'phone', 'debt_amount', 'remaining_credit', 'created_at', 'action']
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private customerService: CustomerService,) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchCustomers()
  }


  fetchCustomers() {
    this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe({
      next: (data: ApiResponse<Customer[]>) => {
        this.customers = data.results;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customers)
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
        console.log(this.customers);

      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        console.error('Error fetching customers', error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('Finished fetching customers');
      }
    });
  }

  Filterchange(data:Event) {
    const value = (data.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = value;
  }
}
```

Below is my customer.component.html

```
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="Filterchange($event)" placeholder="Search by Name" />
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>



        <table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Name</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.first_name}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Phone</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phone}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="debt_amount">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Debt Amount</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.debt_amount}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="remaining_credit">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Remaining Credit</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.remaining_credit}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
                <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Created At</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.created_at | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">Action</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Edit</button>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedcolumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;columns:displayedcolumns"></tr>
        </table>

    </mat-card-content> <br>
    <mat-card-footer>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </mat-card-footer>
</mat-card>
```

And then this is the nature of data coming from my Django server copied from my browser console.

```
{count: 12, next: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers/?limit=2&offset=2', previous: null, results: Array(2)}
count
: 
12
next
: 
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers/?limit=2&offset=2"
previous
: 
null
results
: 
Array(2)
0
: 
account_name
: 
"Sup"
account_number
: 
"3000258536"
address
: 
"Bay Area, San Francisco, CA"
created_at
: 
"2023-12-14T19:18:29.890819Z"
customer_id
: 
"111111"
debt_amount
: 
"4000000.00"
email
: 
"henkelly@gmail.com"
first_name
: 
"Super"
id
: 
30
last_name
: 
"Degea"
other_name
: 
null
phone
: 
"+9745534****"
remaining_credit
: 
"4000000.00"
updated_at
: 
"2023-12-14T19:18:29.890887Z"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
{id: 29, account_name: 'Nke', account_number: '5000337342', created_at: '2023-09-30T11:42:59.448371Z', updated_at: '2023-10-13T11:39:41.762822Z', …}
length
: 
2
```